# iOS app: How to access S3 object saved under cognito identity id folder by another user

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

In my iOS app, i have done AWS Cognito user authentication. Authenticated users are able to upload images to protected folder ie under protected / {cognito user_identitiy_id}. Authenticated users can access objects only saved under their user_identity_id folder. How one user can access objects from others. S3 document says:-

Public: Accessible by all users of your app. Files are stored under the public/ path in your S3 bucket.

Protected: Readable by all users, but writable only by the creating user. Files are stored under protected/{user_identity_id}/ where the user_identity_id corresponds to the unique Amazon Cognito Identity ID for that user.

Private: Only accessible for the individual user. Files are stored under private/{user_identity_id}/ where the user_identity_id corresponds to the unique Amazon Cognito Identity ID for that user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another user that wants to read the file can specify the user that created it:

```
let options = StorageDownloadDataRequest.Options(accessLevel:.protected, targetIdentityId: "OtherUserId")
```

Comment: already set targetidentityid in options {StorageListRequest.Options(accessLevel: .protected,targetIdentityId: "7b6bc346-eb5c-439b-a489-fbd168a02a26")

Comment: you need to append the region code infront of the targetIdentityId eg; "us-west-2:7b6bc346-eb5c-439b-a489-fbd168a02a26"

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Amplify, then using Protected. The owner has write permissions while others can only read files.

Pls help make sure:

1. Your S3 bucket policy is something like this for "Protected" folder to restrict user access: https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_s3_cognito-bucket.html
2. on iOS, assume you're using Amplify, pls follow this: https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/ios/storage. Keep in mind, you have to authenticate and exchange to Credential first before using Storage API.

Comment: my issue is i cannot get other users objects from protected folder

Comment: I've just updated my answers for clarifying, pls take a look.

Comment: { "Condition": {"StringLike": { "s3:prefix": [ "public/", "public/*", "protected/",
                        "protected/*",
                        "private/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/",
                        "private/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow" }. When i change i am getting access denied